# php parse error explode

Tags: php, parsing, explode

I am optimizing my website a bit. Tested the page on local, everything is fine. When I upload it, and access it live, it sudently throws a parse error... but it working perfectly locally, like I said.

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/theriff/www/frvideos.php on line 25
```

the code is the following one:

```
echo explode('|',$youtube[$i])[2].'<br />'."\r\n";
```

$youtube[$i] is a line formated like this:

```
DFHG-LINKYOUTUBE-HJGHJ|french Description|English Description
```

The youtube link only is the ID so there's no '|' symbol in it for sure, and it's read from a text file I write myself manually, so I am sure of the entry.

Does anyone know why it's working fine on local (EasyPhp Developper) but not on the distant server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$results =  explode('|',$youtube[$i]);
echo $results[2].'<br />'."\r\n";
```

Version of PHP is not the same so there's no array chaining available on the 'distant server'.

Comment: yes yes... it works now... thanks you, i will +rep you when i can. Do you have any idea why it was orking as it on local, but not on distant server maybe?

Comment: @user3916429 Because the versions of PHP differ. @knittl has linked to the docs on `Array dereferencing` which has only become available in php 5.4. Your production [read: *distant*] server is running php 5.3 or less.

Answer (score 3):

[Old (< 5.4)](http://php.net/array#example-102) PHP versions cannot directly dereference arrays of function return values, you have to temporarily store the result in a variable:

```
$exploded = explode('|',$youtube[$i]);
echo $exploded[2].'<br />'."\r\n";
```